# RegEx, colon separated list

Tags: regex, list

I am trying to match a list of colon separated emails. For the sake of keeping things simple, I am going to leave the email expression out of the mix and match it with any number of characters with no spaces in between them.

The following will be matched...

```
somevalues  ;somevalues;       somevalues;
```

or

```
somevalues; somevalues             ;somevalues
```

The ending ; shouldn't be necessary.

The following would not be matched.

```
somevalues ;   some values    somevalues;
```

or

```
some values; somevalues some values
```

I have gotten this so far, but it doesn't work. Since I allow spaces between the colons, the expression doesn't know if the space is in the word, or between the colon.

```
([a-zA-Z]*\s*\;?\s*)*
```

The following is matched (which shouldn't e)

```
somevalue ; somevalues  some values;
```

How do I make the expression only allow spaces if there is a ; to the left or right of it?

Comment: ([a-zA-Z]*\s*\;?\s*)* would consider only the first colon if i am not mistaken hence why it matchs the second one aswell.

Comment: here you can know everything you need about regex <strong> [click here](http://www.wellho.net/regex/java.html) </strong>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This following PCRE Expression should work.

`\w+\s*(?:(?:;(?:\s*\w+\s*)?)+)?`

However if putting the email address validation regular expression on this will require
replacing `\w+` with `(?:<your email validation regex>)`

Probabbly This is exactly what you want, tested on http://regexr.com?2rnce

EDIT: However depending on the language you might? need to escape `;` as `\;`

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for. I am using the String.Split in c# but I wanted to validate the textbox on client side before I do anything for performance reasons.

Comment: Can you post the final regex with email address validation ??

Answer (score 6):

Why not just split on semi colon and then regex out the email addresses?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken a semicolon is a valid character in RFC822 email addresses so you should be careful when using this that the emails are guaranteed not to contain any semicolons.

Comment: interesting - wonder how my outlook handles that. I think RFC2822 has superceded but I haven't read that one either.

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from the ? in \;?

```
[a-zA-Z]*(\s*;\s*[a-zA-Z]*)*
```

should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
([a-zA-Z]+\s*;\s*)*([a-zA-Z]+\s*\)?
```

Note that I changed * to + on the e-mail pattern since I assume you don't want strings like `;` to match.

Answer (score 0):

to solve this with regex, you must prepend + append the delimiter to your input lines, otherwise you cannot easily detect the first and last item

```sh
#!/bin/bash

input=a:aa:aaa:aaaa
needle=aa
if [[ ":$input:" =~ ":$needle:" ]]
then
  echo found
else
  echo not found
fi
# -> found
```

.. this takes 45 nanoseconds

bash globbing is faster with 35 nanoseconds

```sh
input=a:aa:aaa:aaaa
needle=aa
if [[ ":$input:" == *":$needle:"* ]]
then
  echo found
else
  echo not found
fi
# -> found
```

stupid solution: split by delimiter and match whole lines. this one is really slow, with 5100 nanoseconds

```sh
echo a:aa:aaa:aaaa | tr ':' $'\n' | grep "^aa$"
# -> aa
```